# Ruby 1.8.7 and Net::HTTP: Making an SSL GET request with client cert?

Tags: ruby, ssl, certificate, client-certificates, net-http

I'm trying to fetch a resource *via* SSL using `Net::HTTP`.  Here is the relevant code fragment:

```
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(ContentURI.path)
https = Net::HTTP.new(ContentURI.host, ContentURI.port)
https.use_ssl = true
https.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(@cert_raw)
https.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(@cert_key_raw)
https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
https.ca_file = File.join(TestDataPath, 'cacert.pem')
resp = https.start { |cx| cx.request(req) }
```

or with the alternate last line:

```
resp = https.get(ContentURI.path)
```

I have verified that the various bits (cert, key, CA cert, *etc.*) are correct.

The problem is that the `cx.request(req)` throws an exception:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A
```

The Apache SSL error log on the server contains the following:

```
[Tue Jan 24 11:47:26 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1876): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 read finished A
[Tue Jan 24 11:47:26 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1905): OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv3 write session ticket A
[Tue Jan 24 11:47:26 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1905): OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv3 write session ticket A
[Tue Jan 24 11:47:26 2012] [info] [client 10.11.88.53] SSL handshake interrupted by system [Hint: Stop button pressed in browser?!]
[Tue Jan 24 11:47:26 2012] [info] [client 10.11.88.53] Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server _SERVERNAME_:443
```

The cert, key, and CA cert file work with this SSL host through other tools; I'm just having trouble reproducing that success programatically using `Net::HTTP[S]`.

Thanks to anyone who can identify what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 7):

I'd say this is matter of your Apache setup rather than problem with Ruby itself.

Check this out:

```
$ curl https://palladium.wejn.cz/sslcerttest/
curl: (56) SSL read: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure, errno 0
$ curl https://palladium.wejn.cz/sslcerttest/ -E client.pem
<pre>Yop.</pre>
```

And then:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'openssl'
require 'uri'

ContentURI = URI.parse("https://palladium.wejn.cz/sslcerttest/")
@cert_raw = File.read('client.pem')
@cert_key_raw = @cert_raw
TestDataPath = '.'

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(ContentURI.path)
https = Net::HTTP.new(ContentURI.host, ContentURI.port)
https.use_ssl = true
https.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(@cert_raw)
https.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(@cert_key_raw)
https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
https.ca_file = File.join(TestDataPath, 'cacert.pem')
resp = https.start { |cx| cx.request(req) }
p resp
p resp.body
```

results in:

```
$ ruby a.rb
#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
"<pre>Yop.</pre>\n"

$ dpkg -l ruby1.8 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $3}'
1.8.7.302-2squeeze1

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]
```

Of course, the apache config in question is:

```
<Directory /var/www/sslcerttest/>
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 5
    SSLCACertificateFile /var/www/sslcerttest/cacert.pem
    SSLCACertificatePath /var/www/sslcerttest/
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth
    SSLRequireSSL
    SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Wejn s.r.o." and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} eq "Server Certificate"
</Directory>
```

Maybe posting additional details (apache config to test against) would be of some help when tracking this issue down...

Comment: looking at the openssl source, the error message is related to missing session ticket (client-supplied data required to resume ssl session); no clue why that's happening in this case...